# Triples of integers satisfying $71 | a^2+b^2-2c^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to count number of triples $(a, b, c) \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 70 \}$ such that$$71 \mid a^2+b^2-2c^2$$I tried to solve the equation$$a^2+b^2=2c^2+71k$$ like a modified Pythagorean equation and then find number of solution for $(a, b, c)$. It led me nowhere. I ran a code and answer is $5041$. Can you help me find a way to count all solutions?

Comment: To find "a solution" is easy: take $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll try to edit it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But he's looking for the total number

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Of course, I know. The last sentence is "Can you help me find a solution for $71\mid a^2+b^2-2c^2$"...

Comment: Observe that $5041=71^2$.

Comment: $$a^2+b^2=2c^2+qkt$$ $$a=p(p+2)t+\frac{t-qk}{2}$$ $$b=p^2t-\frac{t+qk}{2}$$ $$c=p(p+1)t+\frac{t-qk}{2}$$

Answer (score 7):

Since $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $71$, the problem is equivalent to counting the number of the solutions of $a^2+b^2\equiv c^2 \pmod{71}$. This can be rewritten as $a^2\equiv (b-c)(b+c)$, and each time you fix $b$ and $c$, there are two solutions for $a$ when the RHS is a quadratic residue, and zero solution when it is not (there is one $a$ if the RHS is $0$).
Let $x=b+c$ and $y=b-c$. The pair $(x,y)$ is in one-to-one correspondence to the pair $(b, c)$. There are $35\times 35$ pairs of quadratic residues $(x,y)$, and also $35\times 35$pairs of non-quadratic residues. There are $141$ pairs such that $xy=0$.

So the desired number is
$2\times 2\times 35\times 35 +141 = 5041$.

There may be a better solution because this is too long for the answer $5041=71^2$.

Comment: $2$ being a quadratic residue mod $71=8\cdot 8+7$ follows from [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement).

Comment: You also have to use that the solutions $\pm x$ to $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{71}$ must be invertible mod $71$ (which is obvious because $0\not\equiv 2\pmod{71}$) so that no matter what $d$ you pick you can always find a $c$ such that $(\pm x)c\equiv d\pmod{71}$. This is to prove that the problem is equivalent to finding the number of solutions to $a^2+b^2\equiv d^2\pmod{71}$.

Comment: Yes, everything is considered as in $\mathbb{F}_{71}$. You can also directly check that $2$ is a quadratic residue by $12^2=144=2$.